# Bootstrap positioning objects dynamically in columns

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display some objects in 3 columns using Bootstrap 4. When using this code it only appears in 1 column, like this: [web 1 column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHs80.png)

But my idea is to be displayed like this (more or less): [web template 3 columns](https://mdbootstrap.com/freebies/3-columns-listing/).

```
<div class="row-mt-5">
          <div ng-repeat="woman in women">
            <div class= "col-lg-4">
                <!--Card-->
                  <div class="card">
                      <!--Card image-->
                      <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
                      <!--Card content-->
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <!--Title-->
                          <h4 class="card-title">{{woman.name}}</h4>
                          <!--Text-->
                          <p class="card-text"> <h5>{{woman.field}}</h5> <br> {{woman.job}}</p>
                          <a href="#!/women/details/{{woman._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--/.Card-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to learn to use Bootstrap classes for object positioning.

Comment: See the Bootsrap 4 docs: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know about the basic layout structure, [learn it here](https://getbootstrap.com/), Please note that you need to define the grid layout for all the screens **(sm md lg xl)** the details are found in the link provided. Please refer to the below fiddle the code fix for your issue. I have included the ng-app and ng-controller for testing purposes, please ignore that.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class= "col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="woman in women">
      <!--Card-->
      <div class="card">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">{{woman.name}}</h4>
          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text"> 
            <h5>{{woman.field}}{{woman.job}}</h5>
          </p>
        <a href="#!/women/details/{{woman._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0g41eeyn/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This saved my day and my mental health!! I will definitely take a look at the link :)

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is now beta and has changed a lot since the 2 yr old article you've referenced. The `-xs-` infix has been removed. The Bootstrap 4 docs would be better guidance: http://getbootstrap.com/